# Google Cloud us-west1 Cloud Functions not available?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase

I am trying to set up a Cloud Firestore database in the `us-west1` region. However, I am getting the following message:

[image: "Note for Cloud Functions customers: Deploying a function to this location is not yet available. If your function and Storage bucket are in different locations, you could potentially experience increased latency and billing costs. Learn more about selecting function locations based on Cloud Firestore locations."]

I am confused because the docs clearly state in [multiple places](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations) that [`us-west1` supports Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations#tier_1_pricing). Is this warning incorrect? Should I consider picking a different region anyway?

**EDIT**: Apparently [on one page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations) it's NOT listed as a supported region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Cloud Function in Firestore you must follow the listed supported region. Firebase doesn't support `us-west1` according to [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#:%7E:text=Send%20feedback-,Cloud%20Functions%20locations,-bookmark_border). Yes, you may consider picking a different region that suits your requirements.

`us-west` is not yet currently available at this moment.

Whenever `us-west1` is available you may change it on your cloud function however your default region is the one that you've set on your project.

Sample Code:

```
const usFunctions = functions.region('us-west1');
```

But for now it's not yet available. You may choose another region for now but it cannot be changed later.